# The notation of prove dominated converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

This is my question:((Suppose that $f_1,f_2,\ldots,g\colon\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be functions such that $|f_k(n)|\leq g(n)$, $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty g(n)<\infty$, and $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f_k(n)=f(n)$. Then prove that:
\begin{align}
\hspace{-9pt}\limsup_{k\to\infty}\left|\,\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} f_k(n)-\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f(n)\,\right|
&\le\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{|n|\le n_\epsilon}\!\!|f_k(n)-f(n)|+\limsup_{k\to\infty}\!\!\sum_{|n|\gt n_\epsilon}\!\!|f_k(n)-f(n)|.))
\end{align} But my solve: I know that $|\sum a| \le \sum|a|$.
and I think
\begin{align}
\hspace{-9pt}\limsup_{k\to\infty}\left|\,\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} f_k(n)-\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f(n)\,\right| \le \limsup | \sum f_k(n)-f(n)|\le 
\lim \sum | f_k(n)-f(n)|
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Since $|f_k(n)|\leq g(n)$ we obtain $\sum |f_k(n)|\leq \sum g(n)$. Furthermore $\sum g(n)$ is converges,by a theorem in principles of mathematical Analysis (Rudin),hence $\sum |f_k(n)|$ is converges. Finally we have\begin{align}
\hspace{-9pt}\limsup_{k\to\infty}\left|\,\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} f_k(n)-\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f(n)\,\right|
&\le\limsup_{k\to\infty}\!\!\sum_{|n|\gt n_\epsilon}\!\!|f_k(n)-f(n)|.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks but inequality have second part